# How to remove the ghosting effect on the final image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I was given three images which are R, G, and B images. I used `split` to put the RGB into the channel and merge it into one final image. However, I am getting a ghosting effect.

Here is how I did this.

```
IMAGE_PATH = 'was on local'

def readRGBImages(name: str):
    R = cv2.imread('{}/{}.jpg_r.jpg'.format(IMAGE_PATH, name))
    G = cv2.imread('{}/{}.jpg_g.jpg'.format(IMAGE_PATH, name))
    B = cv2.imread('{}/{}.jpg_b.jpg'.format(IMAGE_PATH, name))
    return R, G, B

def mergeRGB(R, G, B):
    _,_,r =cv2.split(R)
    # plt.imshow(R)
    _,g,_ = cv2.split(G)
    # plt.imshow(G)
    b,_,_ = cv2.split(B)
    # plt.imshow(B)
    orgional = cv2.merge([r,g,b])
    plt.imshow(orgional)
    orgional = cv2.cvtColor(orgional, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    return orgional

R, G, B = readRGBImages('3')
cv2.imwrite('3.jpg',mergeRGB(R,G,B))
```

This is my result:
[image: final image]

Comment: if your input images are monochrome, simply use the `IMREAD_GRAYSCALE` flag to `imread`. no need to split each. -- the color planes are misaligned in the inputs already. if your task is to align them, then you need to write code for that. what topics have been covered recently in class?

Comment: Yes, image alignment needs to be used in this assignment. I try to use the code referring to this "https://learnopencv.com/image-alignment-ecc-in-opencv-c-python/" However I still get a ghosting image.  I tried both ways. aligned RGB images or merge them and try to warp the channel.

Comment: if the alignment fails, you need to work on the parameters. ECC expects a reasonably close alignment already. increase sigma, that gives it a wider aperture to work on.